# PDFBox: "you did not close a PDFDocument" right after printing

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I use the following Java Code to print a PDF Document:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintService(printer);
File file = new File(fileName);
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(doc);
job.setPageable(pageable);
System.out.println("-- before printing --");
job.print();
System.out.println("-- after printing --");
doc.close();
```

the output on console is:

```
-- before printing --
Aug 03, 2018 12:05:09 PM org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument finalize
WARNUNG: Warning: You did not close a PDF Document
-- after printing --
```

Why do I get this warning?

Comment: What version are you using? I'm surprised because you do close the document, and the document object isn't "lost". Could it be that there is another document object from other code? E.g. because you called "new PDDocument()" somewhere else?

Comment: I use Version 2.0.11 of PDFBox. If I remove `job.print();` the message disappears. so I don't think the warning is related to another PDDocument. I'll check the rest of the code anyway.

Comment: Another idea - what jdk are you using / is it the latest jdk for that number (6, 7, 8, 9)?

Comment: I just updated from JDK 1.8.0_131 to 1.8.0_181 and the warning is gone. Thank you very much for that hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - the problem went away by updating to the latest jdk version, here: from JDK 1.8.0_131 to 1.8.0_181. I can only suspect that the older jdk had a bug that objects were prematurely marked as "unused" and thus were finalized.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading a PDDocument but not closing it. I suspect you need to do:

```
String yourText;
PDDocument yourDocument = PDDocument.load("yourDocument");
try {
    yourText = pdfs.getText(yourDocument);
} finally {
    yourDocument.close();
}
```

This warning is emitted when the pdf document is finalised and hasn't been closed.

Refer [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSDocument.java) for warning araise:

```
/**
 * Warn the user in the finalizer if he didn't close the PDF document. The method also
 * closes the document just in case, to avoid abandoned temporary files. It's still a good
 * idea for the user to close the PDF document at the earliest possible to conserve resources.
 * @throws IOException if an error occurs while closing the temporary files
 */
protected void finalize() throws IOException
{
    if (!closed) {
        if (warnMissingClose) {
            log.warn( "Warning: You did not close a PDF Document" );
        }
        close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I cannot close the document before I do job.print(); As you see in my code, I close the document right after printing (last line in the snippet) but the message appears at the print method.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please reconsider... my personal attitude is that I only downvote an answer that is blatantly useless. Although this one didn't solve the problem, the part about finalization is correct.